# Change Azure Mobile App service url in client

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have upgraded a backend service to use Azure Mobie App SDK and support for OData queries. I make requests using Postman and recieve desired responses. It is working fine. Now I want to upgrade my client to use Azure Mobile App SDK. The problem I face is that the client SDK uses a hardcoded **tables** in the generated URL. This code:

```
class SiteRepository
{
    private MobileServiceClient client;
    private IMobileServiceSyncTable<Site> siteTable;

    private SiteRepository()
    {
        client = new MobileServiceClient("http://{{host}}/");
        Task.Run(() => InitLocalStoreAsync());
        siteTable = client.GetSyncTable<Site>();

        siteTable.PullAsync("Site", siteTable.CreateQuery());
    }

    private async Task InitLocalStoreAsync()
    {
        if (!client.SyncContext.IsInitialized)
        {
            var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore("localstore.db");
            store.DefineTable<Site>();
            await client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);
        }
    }

    public List<Site> GetSites()
    {
        return Task.Run(() => siteTable.ToListAsync()).Result;
    }
```

sends requests to:

GET `http://{{host}}/tables/site$filter=(updatedAt%20ge ...`

But I want it to send the requests to:

GET `http://{{host}}/api/local/sites?$filter=(updatedAt%20ge...`

Can I somehow change `tables` part to something else?

**Update**:

Here is `SiteController` on the backend:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/local/sites")]
[MobileAppController]
public class SiteController<T> : TableController<T> where T : Model.Entity
{
    protected SiteService<T> service;
    public BaseController(IEntityService<T> _service) 
    {
        service = _service;
    }

    [Route("")]
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public virtual IQueryable<T> Get()
    {
        var entities = service.GetAll();
        if (entities == null || entities.Count() == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return TableUtils.ApplyDeletedFilter(entities.AsQueryable(), Request.AreDeletedRowsRequested());
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to add the code from the custom api? (probably SitesController)

Comment: Added SiteController code, although I don't think it has anything to do with the problem.

Comment: Didn't think you could add `RoutePrefix` to a `TableController` thought you had to inherit from `ApiController` to do that. Then you would have to manually create the Odata goodness. I'm not certain though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With IMobileServiceTable and IMobileServiceSyncTable, requests always use the /tables endpoint. To change this behavior, attach a delegating handler to your MobileServiceClient and change the request URI before it is sent.

Here's an example of a delegating handler that does logging, which shows where you'd add this code: [Log outgoing requests in mobile client](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps/wiki/Help,-my-app-isn't-working!#log-outgoing-requests-in-managed-client-xamarin-windows).